# Get MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY with Self-Signed Certificate on FireFox

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl, firefox, certificate

I got the subject error when trying to use a certificate I created using the following command line:

```
 openssl.exe req -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 3650 -subj "/CN=mysite.local" -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mysite.local.key -out mysite.local.crt
```

I found another issue on this site that referenced the same error:

> Looks like that certificate has a basicConstraints extension with the value cA: TRUE. We stopped allowing CA certificates to act as end-entity certificates. That certificate should be regenerated without the basicConstraints extension. This is also explained at https://wiki.mozilla.org/SecurityEngineering/x509Certs

I followed the referenced link and tried follow the instructions under Self Signed Certs.  Step 1 worked.  Step 2 gave error: Ignoring -days; not generating a certificate.

I'm on Windows 10 Pro, using OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020.  I have not found any reference to that error anywhere on the web.  Any ideas?

Comment: You could check the source: https://github.com/openssl/openssl

Comment: I'm behind schedule too much to take on the task suggested above.  And, since I seem to be only person having this problem, I feel I may be going about this the wrong way.  I'm trying to set up HTTPS for communication between a front end and back end API server that are on different computers on a network.  That is why I was trying to generate a self signed certificate.  Is there a more standard approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding this comment from the OP: " I'm trying to set up HTTPS for communication between a front end and back end API server that are on different computers on a network. That is why I was trying to generate a self signed certificate. Is there a more standard approach to this problem?"**

You can use the script below to create a cert, import it to the trusted root store on the API server, and configure traffic over a given port to use the cert for encryption(SSL I think...). Then, from the cert management GUI (Manage Computer Certificates), you can export the cert you just created and import it into your front-end server.

**Edited to reflect OP's comment on pipeline output issues.**

```bsh
param(
    [string] $certPass,
    [string] $portForTraffic,
    [string] $dnsName = '<HOST>.<DOMAIN>.<DOMAIN_SUFFIX>', # <== ex: server.contoso.com 
    [int] $certValidForDays = 365
)

Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
#Requires -Version 5.0

[string] $certStoreLocation = 'Cert:\LocalMachine'

function CreateSelfSignedCert(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $dnsName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $storeLocation = $certStoreLocation,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [int] $certValidDays = $certValidForDays
){    
    $certificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
        -DnsName $dnsName `
        -CertStoreLocation "$storeLocation\My" `
        -NotAfter $((Get-Date).AddDays($certValidDays)) `
        -Verbose

    $certThumbPrint = $certificate.Thumbprint

    $returnObj = [PSCustomObject] @{
        ThumbPrint = $certThumbPrint;
    }
    return $returnObj;
}

function ExportCert(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $certThumbPrint,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $certPass,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $workDir,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $storeLocation = $certStoreLocation
){    
    $certificatePath = "$storeLocation\My\$certThumbPrint"
    $secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certPass -Force -AsPlainText

    $tempDir = "$workDir\pfx_temp"
    $pfxFilePath = "$tempDir\temp.pfx"    
    if( (Test-Path -Path $tempDir) -eq $false ){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $tempDir -Verbose | Out-Null
    }
    # ...so export it...
    $fileInfo = Export-PfxCertificate `
        -FilePath $pfxFilePath `
        -Cert $certificatePath `
        -Password $secureString `
        -Verbose
    Write-Host "$fileInfo"
    
    return $pfxFilePath
}

function ImportCertToRoot(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $pfxPath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $certPass,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $storeLocation = $certStoreLocation
) {
    $secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certPass -Force -AsPlainText
    Write-Host "Attempting to import cert from: $pfxPath"
    Import-PfxCertificate `
        -FilePath $pfxPath `
        -CertStoreLocation "$storeLocation\Root" `
        -Password $secureString `
        -Verbose | Out-Null
    
    Remove-Item -Path $pfxPath -Force -Verbose
}

function ConfigureSslForPortOnHost(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $port,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $certThumbPrint
) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Attempting to add ssl rule using NETSH. Using cert with thumbprint: $($certThumbPrint)"
    
    Invoke-Expression "netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:$port"
    Invoke-Expression "netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:$port appid='{214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-9caa44b2b74a}' certhash=$($certThumbPrint)"    
}

# Create a self-signed cert
$cert = CreateSelfSignedCert -dnsName $dnsName

# Export the cert so we can later import it to the root store
$pfxPath = ExportCert -certThumbPrint $cert.ThumbPrint -certPass $certPass -workDir $PSScriptRoot

# Import cert to trusted root
ImportCertToRoot -pfxPath $pfxPath -certPass $certPass

# Ensure HTTP traffic to specified port on API server is encrypted
ConfigureSslForPortOnHost -port $portForTraffic -certThumbPrint $cert.ThumbPrint
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this.  Unfortunately, when I run the script (I updated the dnsName line with my dnsName), I now get the following error: The property 'ThumpPrint' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At D:\js-dev\https-app\server\ssl\createcert.ps1:107 char:1
+ $pfxPath = ExportCert -certThumbPrint $cert.ThumpPrint -certPass $cer ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

Comment: @MarkW., just a typo toward the end. Should work now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I had a problem running the script if the tempdir didn't exist before hand.  After a bit of debug and online investigation, I found the problem.  The ExportCert function returned both the tempDir path and the pfxFilePath.  That baffled me for a bit, but I finally found out that Powershell functions return all uncaptured items in the function, not only the item in the return statement.  The New-Item statement did not capture its output, so it got returned as well.  I captured the New-Item into a dummy variable, and that fixed it.  Thanks again for your help.